# How to return a particular pattern from a regex match?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

> "big brown fox"

and I have a regex like this: `(bi|sm)[^\s]+`

So in this case, the match would be "big". Is there a way to return the pattern that was matched, i.e. `bi[^\s]+`?

The idea is to have multiple options separated by the or pipe (like bi and sm in this case) and to be able to tell which one was matched.

I am aware that I could run a separate re.search for each sub-pattern and see whether there's a group(0), but with multiple options that would mean a very long and not concise code.

Here's the full code:

```
str = "big brown fox"
match = re.search(r"(bi|sm)[^\s]+", str)
print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: Make the `\S+` (`[^\s]+` is longer) part of each alterantive and use the solution from the linked thread.